# What branch of functional analysis does this question come under?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following question in my notes.

> Let $A \in H^*$ and let $F=A^{-1}({0})$ $F$ is a closed linear
>   subspace.  Show that for any choice of $u,w \in H$ with $Au$ non zero
>   the vector is $w-\frac{Aw}{Au} u$ is an element of F.

The solution is as below.

> Take $(u_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subset F$ such that $u_j \to u$ in
>   $H$.
>
> We have to show that $u \in F$ but since $A$ is continuous, we get 
>   $$0=\lim_j A(u_j)= A (\lim_j u_j)=A(u)$$
>
> which just means that $u \in F$

I am trying to revise by doing questions from worksheets but I have no idea what branch of functional analysis this question is from and I have no idea what the question is asking and  how the solution answers the question.

So my questions are

> What topic area within functional analysis this question from?
>
> What is the question actually asking?
>
> How does the solution show that $w-\frac{Aw}{Au} u$ is an element of
>   F?

Comment: This solution doesn't seems to answer this question. there is probably an error

Comment: @tryss that is weird and annoying as I am trying to revise.Do you know the solution to the question? If you do I would be so grateful if you could answer it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remember that $F = A^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{ v \in H | A(v) = 0 \}$

To show that $v = w- \frac{Aw}{Au}u \in F$, it suffice to show that $A(v) = 0$.

By linearity of $A$, you have 
$$A(v) = A \left( w- \frac{A(w)}{A(u)}u \right) = A(w) - \frac{A(w)}{A(u)}A(u) = A(w) - A(w) = 0$$

Hence the result

Comment: Why does zero belong to F?

Comment: How did you deuce that $F= \{v \in H \big| A(v)=0 \}$?

Comment: @Aljabra : It is the definition of $A^{-1}(\{0\})$. What did you think the definition of $A^{-1}(\{0\})$ was?

Comment: I dont know, the notation threw me off. What is it was $A^{-1} (\{2x\})$?

Comment: @Aljabra What's $x$ in this context?

Comment: actually ignore the x, what if it was just $A^{-1} (\{2\})$, would it just be $A(v)=2$?

Comment: Let $f: E\to F$ a function, and $B\subset F$, $f^{-1}(B) = \{ x\in E | f(x) \in B \}$. THat's very standard and basic notation

Comment: @tryss I remember that now. Thank you

Comment: @tyrss should that not be $f(x)=B$?

Answer (score 2):

It seems more complicated than it has to be. The point is that:

$$A \left ( w - \frac{Aw}{Au} u \right ) = Aw - \frac{Aw}{Au} Au = Aw - Aw = 0$$

which is the defining property for a vector to be in $F$. Here all I have used is the fact that $A$ is a linear functional defined on all of $H$. No continuity was required, nor was the fact that $F$ is closed.

Comment: Why does it equalling zero the defining property for it to be in F?

Comment: @Aljabra $A^{-1}(0)$ by definition is $\{ u \in H : Au=0 \}$.